# Missing months in Calendar

Tags: php

I am trying to set values of any missing months in my nested array for specific years.

**Data:**

```
$data = array(
    '2019'=>array('January'=>224, 'March'=>66, 'September'=>301),
    '2018'=>array('April'=>45, 'August'=>116, 'November'=>38)
);
```

As you can see in the above array, year 2019 and 2018 have missing months. How can I can add those missing months and set the values to zero? Please advice.

Comment: Create an array that lists all the months. Loop through that array, and add it as a key with value 0 if the key doesn't already exist.

Comment: Nest that into a loop that loops over all the years in `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace) to overlay one array with another.

```
$months=json_decode('{"January":0,"February":0,"March":0,"April":0,"May":0,"June":0,
"July":0,"August":0,"September":0,"October":0,"November":0,"December":0}',true);

$data = array(
    '2019'=>array('January'=>224, 'March'=>66, 'September'=>301),
    '2018'=>array('April'=>45, 'August'=>116, 'November'=>38)
);

foreach ($data as $year=>$v) 
$data[$year]=array_replace($months,$data[$year]);

print_r ($data);
```

If there is a key present in `data`, then its value is used, otherwise the value from `months` is used.

[Teh Playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/R2DvjD6JRaEJKjj5)

[Code for months array (apHarmony)](https://www.apharmony.com/software-sagacity/2014/07/php-one-liners-array-of-month-names-and-numbers/)

Comment: Thank you so much!!, This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This one is using a nested loop, you can also see,

```
//Month array creation
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){ 
    $months[$m] = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)); 
}

$data = array( '2019'=>array('January'=>224, 'March'=>66, 'September'=>301), '2018'=>array('April'=>45, 'August'=>116, 'November'=>38) ); 

//The iteration
foreach($data as $year => $val){ 
    foreach($months as $month => $monthval){ 
        $newdata[$year][$monthval] = !empty($data[$year][$monthval]) ? $data[$year][$monthval] : 0 ; 
    } 
} 

echo json_encode($newdata);
```